# pySnmp: impossible to change source address

Tags: pysnmp

Using `pySnmp 4.4.12`, I can successfully send `v3` traps, but it seems impossible to change the source address (see below code), as it can be done for `v1` use case (by adding a further specific var bind).

Any ideas?

Thank you for your kind help

Code:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    sendNotification(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData('public'),
        UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 162)),
        ContextData(),
        'trap',
        NotificationType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.20408.4.1.1.2.0.432'),
        ).addVarBinds(
            # agent uptime
            ('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0', 12345),
            # agent address
            ('1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.3.0', '127.0.0.1'),
            # enterprise OID
            ('1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0', '1.3.6.1.4.1.20408.4.1.1.2'),
            # user variable-bindings may follow
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the same issue !! :(

In the context of sending SNMP v3 traps with PySNMP 4.4.12, changing the source address directly within the library might not be supported as it is for SNMP v1. SNMP v3, being a more secure version of SNMP, may have different considerations for source address handling.

If the PySNMP library does not provide a direct method to set the source IP address for SNMP v3 traps, you may need to rely on the operating system or network configurations to control the source address.

Comment: I'll give it a try, as at present, I'm working on another project. Nevertheless, the pysnmp library, at least in the mentioned release seems to have such an issue. Another possibility might be to subclass the original class and so to "implement" NAT, or, more simply, fix the bug. Thank you anyways!

Comment: If it helps accept my answer. So that it can help community.

Comment: This is simply the wrong answer. SNMP v1 TRAP message format contains a field for agent source IP, while v2 TRAP message format removes that. So, this library can set it for v1 TRAP as the question body described, but impossible for v2/v3 TRAP, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679137/snmp-v1-v2c-and-v3-trap-difference

Comment: based on the specific context of the original question regarding PySNMP 4.4.12 and the challenge of changing the source address for SNMP v3 traps, your view of response is more accurate. In SNMP v3, the TRAP message format may not provide a direct mechanism to set the source IP address within the PySNMP library, as it does for SNMP v1. Your clarification is aligned with the version-specific details and the user's scenario, making their response more applicable in this context. Agreed and thanks!

Comment: original answer about configuring the network for specific routing or using network address translation (NAT) to modify the source IP address remains valid. Additionally, you may want to consider if there are any specific features or updates in newer versions of PySNMP that address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP v1 TRAP message format contains a field for agent source IP, while v2 TRAP message format removes that. So, this library can set it for v1 TRAP as the question body described, but impossible for v2/v3 TRAP.

More details can be found in [SNMP v1,v2c and v3 trap difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679137/snmp-v1-v2c-and-v3-trap-difference)